# How to talk to a web server from a C program

Tags: javascript, php, c

I write a c program that reads some system data like RAM, SWAP memory, Uptime and many other things. And I want to display them into a webpage. But I don't know how webpage to get data data from my c program. I thought they can communicate through files but file operations are slow. How can I get data from my c program?

Comment: You can write a PHP c extension.

Comment: [Getting Started with CGI Programming in C](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html)

Comment: Something like this maybe: https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ Web Server Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/c-c-web-server-library)

Comment: Do you already have a web-server up and running, which should provide the data by the program you are writing?

Comment: I like short answers, however this is to short form me to safely parse.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `popen` to communicate with your C program. See the official documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php). Then JavaScript can poll your PHP script that asks the C program for RAM and SWAP usage.